# org.hibernate.query.Query.list deprecated

Tags: hibernate

I'm using SessionFactory (hibernate specific) methods.

org.hibernate.query.Query.list is deprecated. What is the non deprecated way to obtain results from a hibernate query? I can't believe I'm having this difficult a time trying to find this :)

For example:

```
<UploadStatus> query = session.createQuery("select us from UploadStatus us where us.uploadFileId = :uploadFileId")
    .setParameter("uploadFileId", fileUploadId); code here
 List<UploadStatus> us = query.list();
```

The list() method above is deprecated. What is the proper/non deprecated replacement for this?

Thanks
-Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getResultList() method instead of list(). The getResultList() is declared in both TypedQuery and org.hibernate.Query (depricated) interfaces. The default implementation of getResultList() in org.hibernate.Query calls the list() method. But since its also declared in TypedQuery, I guess editor shouldn't show is as depricated.